# Java regex not matching - in perl OK

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex that works OK in perl. However in java I am getting an exception when running this code.

```
    String procTime="125-23:02:01";
    String pattern = "([0-9]+)-([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+).*";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher mt = r.matcher(procTime);
    String a = mt.group(0); // throws exception not fnd
    String d = mt.group(1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not calling [**`Matcher#find`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) or [**`Matcher#matches`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) command in your code. Following will work:

```
String procTime="125-23:02:01";
String pattern = "([0-9]+)-([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+).*";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher mt = r.matcher(procTime);
if (mt.find()) {
   String a = mt.group(0); // should work now
   String d = mt.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank You.  (comment must be at least 15 char in length)